# Can you append to a data frame, while simultaneously adding in and populating a field into the appended data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Can you append to a data frame (say from df_A -to- df_B), while simultaneously populating a new field into the appended data frame (df_B)?

I'm appending rows of df_A into df_B under certain situations, but I'd love to populate a field in df_B with a string that explains why the appending occurs at the time of the append.  The idea being I can have a string that reports what errors occurred and why the row needs to be removed from df_A.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_A = pd.DataFrame(data={"Acol": [1, 1, 2, 3], "Bcol": [1, 'a', 2, 'b']})

df_B = df_A.loc[df_A['Bcol'].apply(type) == int]

# need to occur at time of append, as this error message should vary with each check
df_B = df_B.assign(NewString='because Bcol was int, etc etc')
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the kind of behaviour you're describing? It isn't really clear to me what you're trying to do. Also, I think the code example you shared code be improved.

Comment: I made some changes to the code, let me know if I understood things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make the *assignment* on the *filtered* DataFrame.

```
>>> dfa
   Acol Bcol
0     1    1
1     1    a
2     2    2
3     3    b
>>> mask = dfa['Bcol'].apply(type) == int
>>> dfb = dfa[mask].assign(New='bbbbb')
>>> dfb
   Acol Bcol    New
0     1    1  bbbbb
2     2    2  bbbbb
>>>
```

I have a feeling that this isn't what you want `should vary with each check` implies there are multiple checks but each iteration of `dfb = dfa...` will create a new `dfb`.